# Regex to grab content from another page

Tags: php, regex

I am using the following code:

`preg_match('/url_encoded_fmt_stream_map=(.*?)&/', $response, $fmt_url)`

to grab the url_encoded_fmt_stream_map contents from the following url:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ufDIdRyMklw

but it isn't returning anything.

What am I doing wrong? This used to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('/url_encoded_fmt_stream_map=(.*?)\\\\u0026amp;/si', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[1];
} else {
    $result = "";
}
```

there is no & sign in the same sentince so there \\u0026amp; is a kind of & sign encoded. but your code didnt work because /{REGEX}/s   the "s" was missing for the dot equals new line

Answer (score 0):

could it be a delimiter problem?or URL encode? for me `url_encoded_fmt_stream_map=(.*?)%26` works